# Bootstrap Table Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table with several options like search, refresh and pagination. Here is a `plunk`:http://plnkr.co/edit/ufBxbzLj98bZ3nxkaEXV?p=preview.

Now the issue is: The json data returned from URL used in the above plunk is is in the below format:

```
[{"userId": 1,"id": 1,"title": ".....","body": "......"}]
```

Here is the URL in above format: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

That's fine but the same table is not working for JSON data in the below format:

```
{"records":[ {"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"}]}
```

Here is URL in above format: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php

I have tried using below, but didnt get the result:

```
  <table data-toggle="table" data-search="true"
   data-show-refresh="true"
   data-show-toggle="true"
   data-show-columns="true"
   data-url="http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php"
   data-query-params="queryParams"
   data-pagination="true"
   data-height="500">
```

Seems the logic behind would be simple, but couldn't sortit. Would be grateful if anyone can help!!

Comment: `var data = {"records":[ {"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"}]}`. Now `data.records` will help populate your table

Comment: @sagarpatro: I have to use dynamic data from URL. How can I do that

Comment: The url you have provided in plunker results in a object array. But what you are trying to achieve the same using a object which contain the object array. Now for the same either you need to change the response or you need to change your table. you can use jQuery data table and provide `data.records` there.